# MVC 5 / Bind dropdownlist including disabled values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, dropdownlistfor

(*My first quesion, I'm quite impressed :)* )

First, please excuse my English, I'm French ;)

My issue is about DropDownList which is linked(bind) to a required field (F, int) of an object O (edited in a view V) and contains a list of elements (LE), some of them disabled.

The behavior I want in the view :

- when I create an object, the validation must trigg if nothing
  is selected in the list (OK)
- when I create an object, the disabled elements of the list must not be selectable (OK)
- when I edit an object, if the field is among enabled values, same behavior (OK)
- when I edit an object, if the field is among disabled values, it must be displayed and selected when viewed (OK)
- when I edit an object, if the field is among disabled values, when I post data, the client validation must authorize disabled values to be validated (OK with a little javascript)

My issue :

- when I edit an object, if the field is among disabled values, when I
  post data, the model contains null for the field linked to the
  dropdownlist even if I include an hidden field with the Id.

Here is some of my code to help understand my issue.

Any idea of how I could include disabled values of my dropdown list in the model when I post data ?

Thanks for any help !

---

View :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Currencies, new { @class = "form-control ignore-desactivated" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Currency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(function () {
    $('form').validate().settings.ignore = '.ignore-desactivated';
});
```

Source when edition :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control ignore-desactivated" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Currency_Id" name="Currency.Id">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="9">Angolan kwanza (desactivated)</option>
        <option value="10">Argentine peso</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="1">Euro (desactivated)</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="56">Gibraltar pound (desactivated)</option>
        <option value="3">Great Britain Pound</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Currency" data-valmsg-[replace][1]="true"></span>
</div>
```

My model when I want to save data :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ9aH.png

Answer (score 0):

... and I found an answer a few minutes after asking it (thanks to my colleagues)...

I don't know if that's correct, but a little js code to remove disabled items before the post did the trick :

```
//Delete disabled elements of lists before submit
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('.ignore-desactivated').each(function () {
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    })
})
```